# React .map function rendering everything 3 times rather than once

Tags: reactjs, duplicates, rendering, react-props, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to render my array of objects once but for some reason its multiplying three times. Ideally, you should be able to use the search bar to filter through the workouts(array of objects) and it get the specified item. However, the search bar and the three workouts are rendered three times. Could this be to do with the fact that I'm passing props from my Home file using a map function and then using another map to filter searches in my WorkoutDetails file?

I've tried to specify a particular index in the filteredItems.map function but It still repeats 3 times. This makes me think its a problem with passing props to the file using a map function.

Code Below: **Home.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useWorkoutsContext } from "../hooks/useWorkoutsContext";

//components
import WorkoutDetails from "../components/WorkoutDetails";
import WorkoutForm from "../components/WorkoutForm";

const Home = () => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/workouts");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_WORKOUTS", payload: json });
      }
    };
    fetchWorkouts();
  }, [dispatch]);
  console.log(workouts, "HOMEPAGE");

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="workouts">
        {workouts &&
          workouts.map((workout) => (
            <WorkoutDetails key={workout.title} workout={workout} />
          ))}
      </div>

      <WorkoutForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**WorkoutDetials:**

```
import { useWorkoutsContext } from "../hooks/useWorkoutsContext";
import { useState } from "react";
//date fns
import formatDistanceToNow from "date-fns/formatDistanceToNow";

const WorkoutDetails = ({ workout }) => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [load, setLoad] = useState("");
  const [reps, setReps] = useState("");
  const [set, setSet] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/workouts/" + workout._id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch({ type: "DELETE_WORKOUT", payload: json });
    }
  };

  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const workouts = { title, load, reps, set };

    const response = await fetch("/api/workouts/" + workout._id, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(workouts),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    const json = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      setError(json.error);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      setError(null);
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_WORKOUT", payload: json });
    }
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const getFilteredItems = (query, workouts) => {
    if (!query) {
      return workouts;
    }
    return workouts.filter((workout) => workout.title.includes(query));
  };
  

  const filteredItems = getFilteredItems(query, workouts);
  console.log(filteredItems, "FILTERED ITEMS");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div className="workout-details">
        <div>
          {filteredItems.map((workout) => (
            <div key={workout._id}>
              <h4>{workout.title}</h4>
              <p>
                <strong>Load (kg): </strong>
                {workout.load}
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Number of reps: </strong>
                {workout.reps}
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Number of sets: </strong>
                {workout.set}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
          <p>
            {formatDistanceToNow(new Date(workout.createdAt), {
              addSuffix: true,
            })}
          </p>
        </div>
        <button className="material-symbols-outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
          delete
        </button>
        <div>
          {!open ? (
            <div>
              <button
                className="material-symbols-outlined"
                onClick={() => setOpen(!false)}
              >
                update
              </button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <button
                className="material-symbols-outlined"
                onClick={() => setOpen(!true)}
              >
                update
              </button>
              <form className="create" onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
                <h3>UPDATE - {workout.title}</h3>

                <label>Excersize Title:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  value={title}
                />

                <label>Load (in kg):</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => setLoad(e.target.value)}
                  value={load}
                />

                <label>Number of Reps:</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => setReps(e.target.value)}
                  value={reps}
                />

                <label>Number of Sets:</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  onChange={(e) => setSet(e.target.value)}
                  value={set}
                />

                <button>update</button>
                {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorkoutDetails;
```

Comment: Yea, it's because you're mapping over the workouts collection twice.

Comment: Maybe... you're doing too much in WorkoutDetails? Currently it seems to serve two purposes, presenting a filtered list of workouts AND presenting workout details. I'd assume, given the name of the component, the original intent was for this component to just be the details bit and not include searching and listing.

Comment: Cheers for the info. If I were to bring the search functionality out, how would I then pass that function back to the workoutDetails to then filter through the data as that's where its presented?